# Wsdl file can't access through browser

Tags: php, xml, wsdl, ivr

here is the thing, I have two different webservices which is **both working on SoapUI**. However, when I try to load the other webservice on the browser http://xxx.xx.xxx/test?wsdl, it is returning an 404 error. I can't give the URL here since it has restricted access unless allowed.

Comment: 404 is page not found. You have to check if the page exists.

Comment: if its php page try putting `test.php` it should work. http://xxx.xx.xxx/test.php?wsdl

Comment: Hi. If I add .asmx before the ?wsdl (http://xxx.xx.xxx/test.asmx?wsdl) it would work, I only need the ?wsdl ending without asmx since I will load it on IDE

Comment: Sorry did not understand your last statement.

Comment: Hi. What i mean is that if I add .asmx before the ?wsdl. I can access it thru browser. I only want the website name and the end is ?wsdl. But doesn't work.

Comment: Try out my solution and let me know if it work outs for you.

Answer (score 0):

Enable `.htaccess` on your webserver and add the below commands to your file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.asmx -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.asmx
```

This will allow you access url:  `xxx.xx.xxx/test?wsdl`